# c++ 14 compiler for OS X

Tags: c++, macos

can someone recommend a compiler that supports c++ 14 on the OS X platform? I'm studying programming and principles by Bjarne Stroustrup and need some assistance with acquiring the appropriate compiler for the context of the book (c++ 14).

Comment: Yes, Clang has full support.

Comment: @chris Which version of clang?

Comment: @trojanfoe, Clang 3.4 finished off C++14 and the SVN version has C++1z support. GCC didn't support all of C++14 last I checked, not to mention the standard library.

Answer (score 12):

The best compiler for use on OS X is clang. C++14 is fully supported in clang as of 3.4: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html.

The current Xcode 6 betas come with a 3.4 based clang so you can just use that.

(Source: I am a compiler engineer working at Apple)

Comment: I also just checked. Xcode 5.1 (currently in the Mac App Store) has a clang 3.4 variant too, so that should work as well.

Comment: That is a good source :)

Answer (score 1):

You should install [Macports](http://macports.org) and then you have a choice of GCC 4.8 or 4.9 and Clang 3.5 or 3.6 by simply typing:

```
$ sudo port install clang-36
```

or

```
$ sudo port install gcc49
```

Note: you'll want to have Xcode installed first.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 with OS X 10.8. Therefore do I need to upgrade Xcode

Comment: @d_blk No; however you will need Xcode installed in order for Macports to compile some ports (which might not be any in your case).

Comment: I would not suggest using macports. If you already have an up-to-date Xcode (5.1.1 is up-to-date) you already have a compiler with c++14 support.

Comment: @Beanz Macports gives you the ability to choose which compiler you want to use with very little effort.  Choice is a good thing.

Comment: @trojanfoe, Sure... But Macports also tends to mutate aspects of the OS X Unix shell environment in non-trivial ways. Depending on what you install it can replace normal base system utilities with its own versions that behave differently and it changes your system path to make those versions default. It is a very big hammer. My point here is that OP was asking for a C++14 compiler, and there are much simpler ways to get one on OS X than macports.

Answer (score 1):

The standard compiler provided by apple is Clang. Here it claims it is c++14 aware:

http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx14

To get it available I think the easiest way is to install Xcode.